# Does Deezer always include local music in Flow?

Tags: deezer

I'm using Deezer Free and I'm getting plenty of recommendations for local music (southeast Europe).

I don't normally listen to any of this music and it's a pain skipping them at all times.

Does anyone perhaps know if upgrading to Deezer Premium removes these suggestions, or is there a setting that should be changed?